# After trying view Bitmap image in Android studio 3.2 app crashes

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm trying to develop an android app android studio 3.2. When app crashes `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` 
stopped the app. This  is my code to get an image in drawable

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button button;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_click);

        try {
            this.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.helloworld);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("error_msg", ""+e);
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+e);

        }
//
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and also i used this

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'

How to solve this issue?

```
D/error_msg: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
```

This is the error i got when Catch the error

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: post your crash log to get better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the calls `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()` to the top of `OnCreate()` method. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_click);

    try {
        this.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.helloworld);

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("error_msg", ""+e);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+e);
    }
}
```

The layout has to be set before calling `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set image resource to ImageView by using `setImageResource`

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.helloworld);
```

If you specifically want to add bitmap then try to debug and check the error which leads to crash.

Comment: D/error_msg: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference this is the error i got

Comment: so your imageView is null

Comment: did you added ImageView  imageView  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageviewid) this?

Comment: ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view); yes i added this line

Comment: add your full class in question. so that we can understand

Comment: I added full class can you check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185540/discussion-between-uma-achanta-and-ruc).

Comment: check once you have helloworld image in drawable folder of mipmap folder.

Comment: I found the error is super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); this code add top of the code then it work thank you

Comment: you forget to add setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_name);

Comment: what happened? setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_name); Isn't it the cause?